# ondraw function is not calling in mfc?

Tags: mfc

I have a dialog in which I made list control and made its ownerdraw true. But on draw function of dialog is not calling for list. What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BS_OWNERDRAW is a message that redraws the control with linked bitmap.

Try this->RedrawWindow();

Redraws the whole window (and your list as well).